# Mixing date frequencies in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have the query below:

```
select s1.DATADATE, s1.PRCCD, c.EBIT
from sec_dprc s1 
left outer join rdq_temp c 
on s1.GVKEY = c.GVKEY
and s1.DATADATE = c.rdq
where s1.GVKEY = 008068
order by s1.DATADATE
```

I am trying to create a rolling calculation that between the two columns, the PRCCD column is daily prices and the EBIT column is a quarterly value. I want to be able to calculate the product of the two, i.e PRCCD*EBIT for everyday but the EBIT only changes once a quarter on random dates. Summarizing, I want to be able to calculating the product of EBIT and PRCCD going forward using only new values of EBIT when they change each quarter randomly

```
DATADATE                PRCCD   EBIT
1984-02-01 00:00:00.000 28.625  NULL
1984-02-02 00:00:00.000 27.875  NULL
1984-02-03 00:00:00.000 26.75   420.155
1984-02-06 00:00:00.000 27      NULL
1984-02-07 00:00:00.000 26.875  NULL
```

.
.
.

```
DATADATE                PRCCD   EBIT
1984-05-02 00:00:00.000 30.75   NULL
1984-05-03 00:00:00.000 30.875  NULL
1984-05-04 00:00:00.000 30.75   NULL
1984-05-07 00:00:00.000 31.125  499.228
1984-05-08 00:00:00.000 31.75   NULL
```

.
.
.

```
1984-07-31 00:00:00.000 25.625  NULL
1984-08-01 00:00:00.000 26.75   NULL
1984-08-02 00:00:00.000 26.375  348.364
1984-08-03 00:00:00.000 26.75   NULL
1984-08-06 00:00:00.000 27      NULL
```

Thanks for the help!

one of the solutions I came to:

```
select TD.Date, TD.C CD, TQ.C CQ, TQ.C1, TQ.C/TQ.C1 EBITps,TQ.C/TQ.C1/TD.C PE
from 
(select DataDate date, PRCCD C from sec_dprc where GVKEY = 008068) TD
cross apply (select top 1 rdq date, ebit C, csh12q C1 from rdq_temp  where rdq<=TD.Date order by rdq desc) TQ
order by TD.Date
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a non-equijoin between the two tables.  This would be much easier if you had effective and end date on the rdq_temp data.  In order to add them in SQL Server, you can do a self join and aggregation (other databases support lag() and lead() functionality).

The following query does this where condition on the join is essentially a "between":

```
with rdq as (
    select r.datadate, r.ebit, min(rnext.datadate) as nextdatadate
    from rdq_temp r left outer join
         rdq_temp rnext
         on r.datadate < rnext.datedate
    group by r.datadate, r.ebit
)
select  datadate, prccid, rdq.ebit
from sec_dprc sd left outer join
     rdq
     on sd.datadate >= rdq.datadate and rdq.datadate < rdq.nextdatadate
```

I'm guessing that data by quarters is not very big, so this should work fine.  If you had more data, I would strongly suggest having effective and end dates, rather than just the asof date, in the rdq records.

Answer (score 0):

I havent checked the performance of this one, but I think it gives the result you want.

```
select  datadate
        ,prccid
        ,ebit
        ,(  select  top 1 ebit 
            from    sec_dprc s2 
            where   s2.datadate <= s1.datadate 
                and ebit is not null 
            order by datadate desc
        ) as latestEbit
from    sec_dprc s1
```

Comment: This will have exponentially worse performance as the size of `sec_dprc` increases.